# the com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete in app store

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

Regarding 2.5.1, we found that your app uses or references the com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete

API.

To resolve this issue, it would be appropriate to revise your binary and remove any references to the non-public or deprecated APIs that we have identified.

I search in my project I did not find out  com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete in project